# Jmeter java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jmeter

I have the error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException

When i want to add a view result in tree for a post http request.

Here is what i did :

[image: desc]

I have the last version (5.0) and i am using fedora 28. And that my first time using apache Jmeter (i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969120/jmeter-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-running-a-few-users) post but that say that i have to upgrade to 2.0 but i am in 5.0)

Is that a bad configuration that i did ? Or a fedora bug ? ..

Comment: can you show the full stacktrace with nullpointerexception please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that you need to **remove the tick** from the `Use multipart/form-data` box

[image]

If you have this enabled - JMeter sends a [multipart request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1) and your server might fail to handle it.

Also looking into the nature of your request my expectation is that you should send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type). This can be done via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager):

[image]

In case of further issues please update your question with the relevant part of [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging)